# How can I select the last day of the month for the nearest past month for a specific month?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I've got a date column that represents a user's birthday, but the year is not used (to avoid age data, which can be sensitive for some users :)). I need to compare it to another column to see if the user has completed training since the last occurrence of the last day of their birth month.

In other words, if the `training_date` occurs after the last day of the month of the last occurrence of their birth month *in the past*. For this question, assume the birthday column is called `birthday`.

```
where `training`.`date_training` BETWEEN MAKEDATE(Year(CURDATE()) -1,dayofyear(`user`.`birthdate`)) AND MAKEDATE(Year(CURDATE()) -1,dayofyear(`user`.`birthdate`));
```

Edit: `birthday` is stored with an arbitrary year, currently the informal business rule is use the year the record was entered.

Comment: can you add the query that you tried?

Comment: I haven't come up with anything that will even compile! This is just a part of the where clause in a complex correlated subquery in a dialect that is not my area of expertise, sorry :/

Comment: I have considered selecting the last date of the birth month of this year and the one prior, then comparing them to the current date, but I'm having a hard time deciding on the proper date/time functions in MySQL. Is last_day the way to go? @Jodrell doesn't seem to think so...

Comment: what do you store for `birthday` year if this is a date column?

Comment: if you don't consider year in the comparison, you can simply do a month comparison like `MONTH(training_date) > MONTH(birthday)`

Comment: if the year is not used, how do you know that the training has occurred after the birthday? eg. if birthday is on december and the training is on january, how do you know which one comes first?

Answer (score 1):

if year is considered

```
(YEAR(training_date) > YEAR(birthday)) || ((YEAR(training_date) = YEAR(birthday)) && (MONTH(training_date) > MONTH(birthday)))`
```

else if month only,

```
MONTH(training_date) > MONTH(birthday)
```

Comment: You need to know if its last year or this year depending on whether the birthday has occured yet this year.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.  I am still unclear on they way the birthday is stored.  So i have provided both options depending on the possibilities.

Comment: Hi I added more content, hopefully this is more clear